# How to extend from multiple eslint standards?

Tags: eslint

This is the existing .eslintrc,

```
{
    "extends": "airbnb-base",
}
```

Now i'm hoping to extend from multiple standards, e.g.

```
{
    "extends": ["airbnb-base", "semistandard"]
}
```

But it's not working.

I do understand 2 standards couple conflict with each other, but in "rules" section in .eslintrc, i hope to override those.